# CoreBluetooth Fire a method when other device is asking to pair?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am new to Corebluetooth.framework, I want to fire a simple method when other device
wants to connect to ios device.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot intercept the connection event, nor the service discovery. The first time you even "hear" about a central being connected to your device (acting as the peripheral) is when the central is trying to *read*, *write* dynamic characteristics or *subscribes* for notifications.

If you have a scenario in mind where the central lets know the peripheral that it is there and the peripheral can start doing something with this info, then you need to implement this in a proprietary way using any of the *read*, *write* or *subscribe* events.

Additional note: you cannot force a central to disconnect from your peripheral. The only way to do this is the deallocation of the CBPeripheralManager. But even in that case, iOS will decide when to really close the connection.